# Fixing Error 1 "side location conflict" using clip raster by mask layer

Tags: qgis, buffer, clip, altitude

I use QGIS version 3.34.3 and Windows 10.

**what I did so far:**

- I downloaded the data from COSMOS Europe here: https://doi.tereno.net/landingpage/doi/https%3A%2F%2Fapi.datacite.org%2Fdois%2F10.34731%252Fx9s3-kr48
- saved the file "General_Information" from this dataset so that each heading appeared in a column. You can download it here if you need: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P_wPyuD8wuLcU-_kGjUJIz7vIrTQi-hT?usp=drive_link
- I downloaded a DEM here: https://www.mapsforeurope.org/access-data  ("EuroDEM")
- I defined a mountainous area as the following:

[image]

- I loaded eurodem raster layer into QGIS
- I added the csv-file "general_information" into GQIS (layer -> add layer -> delimited text -> file name “general_information_stations_ID” -> x field “longitud” -> y field “latitude” -> proof sample data -> add)
- I exported the layer as shape file (save layer as shape file -> export layer -> save feature as -> ESRI shape file -> file name “stations_coordinates_ID.shp”)
- I calculated slope (
  raster -> analysis -> slope -> input “eurodemo” -> run;
  rename layer “eurodem_slope”
  export layer as GEOtiff -> export -> save as -> file name “eurodem_slope_new” -> create options -> high compression -> ok;
  use tool “sample raster values” -> Input Layer “stations_coordinates_ID”
  -> raster layer “eurodem_slope” -> output column “slope” -> sampled save to file -> name “slope_stations_ID2” as shape file
  -> save -> run)

In the attribute table are now slope values added

- I tried to calculate the local elevation range, which is the difference between maximum and minimum altitude in a region. I took each station and a radius of 7 km
- I brought both datasets into the coordinate system EPSG:6258
  (export -> save as -> ... "eurodem_EPSG6258" and "stations_coordinates_ID_EPSG6258")
- I used the tool multipart to single part for "stations_coordinates_ID_EPSG6258" and saved it as "stations_coordinates_ID_EPSG6258_singleparts"
- I used the tool buffer (input layer -> "stations_coordinates_ID_EPSG6258_singleparts" -> distance 7.0 km -> end cape style round -> buffered save to file "stations_coordinates_ID_EPSG6258_singleparts_buffer.shp" ->run)

**Here the buffer is not round but ellipsoidal - is that because of the projection or is there an error?**

- now I want to extract the altitude values for each buffer area first and then define maximum and minimum of each of these buffer areas
- I use "clip raster by mask layer" (input layer "eurodem_EPSG6258 -> mask layer "stations_coordinates_ID_EPSG6258_singleparts_buffer" -> match the extent of the clipped raster to the extent of the mask layer -> profile high compression -> clipped (mask)  save to file "eurodem_EPSG6258_clipped.tif" -> run)

And here is the problem: I always get the an error message, which is
"**ERROR 1: TopologyException: side location conflict at 127294.89636593655 38611.379855406813. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid**."

Comment: Why your buffers are ellipses and not circles is because there is some ambiguity with EPSG:6258. One is the [European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble](https://epsg.io/6258-datum) and one is the [MAGNA-SIRGAS / Mitu urban grid](https://epsg.io/6258), for use in Colombia. Filtering in QGIS with 6258 gives the latter. However, if you refer to the *Remarks* section of the ETR - *"Has been realized through ETRF89, ..., ETRF2005 and ETRF2014."*. Therefore, you can use one of these codes instead. The most recent is probably the most appropriate.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, the *ETRF2014* reference system is not projected. You might want to consider using a UTM zone instead.

Comment: I made an answer that suggested dissolving the buffer result which stops the exception occurring. However, I realise now that you want to calculate statistics for each buffer area. Using *Clip raster by mask layer* as you have described will not achieve this, it creates a single raster with cell values where the mask features are. It does not create a raster for each feature. Take a look at *Zonal statistics* instead. It creates a new vector layer (in this case your buffers) with selected statistics of the raster in added attribute columns.

Comment: Hey, when I try to save the eurodem layer as UTM, I get an error message. I will have a look on zonal statistics the upcoming days. Thanks for the tip!